# Validate Attachment Content Type Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is it possible to enforce a 'content type' validation in [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) without enforcing a 'presence' validation (i.e. allow blanks)? I currently have:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
end
```

However, this fails if no attachment is present. For example:

```
>> @person = Person.new
>> @person.save
>> @person.errors.first
=> ["picture_content_type", "is not one of image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png"]
```

Is it possible to do the validation only if an attachment is included.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure that method is the cause of your failure; Here's my simple class

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, {
            :styles => { :large => "700x400#", :medium=>"490x368#", :thumbnail=>"75x75#" },
            :default_url => "/images/thumbnail/blank-recipe.png"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /image/ 
end
```

Then, if I:

```
Image.new.valid?
#this is true
```

You might be doing other paperclip validations, though. Can you post a simple example?

Comment: I updated the sample code above slightly. When I perform 'Person.new.valid?'  the result is false. I'm running Rails 2.3.8 and Paperclip 2.2.15.

Comment: If I understand you correctly `:content_type => /image/` represents a list of image file types. Do you know what that list includes, where in the Paperclip code it is stored and if this exits for other kinds of files such as documents?

Comment: @Btuman https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/validators/attachment_content_type_validator.rb#L70

Comment: Watch out of last `}` in 
`:default_url => "/images/thumbnail/blank-recipe.png"}`
This will cause error.

Answer (score 10):

#### Working example

In the following model only *image/png, image/gif and image/jpeg* are valid content types for the image attachment.

```
class Photo
  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, 
                                    :content_type => /^image\/(png|gif|jpeg)/
end
```

#### Specs

```
describe Photo do
  it { should validate_attachment_content_type(:image).  
              allowing('image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg').      
              rejecting('text/plain', 'text/xml', 'image/abc', 'some_image/png') }
end
```

#### More info

You could also take a look at the ***[AttachmentContentTypeValidator](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/validators/attachment_content_type_validator.rb)*** class with is responsible for doing the validation.

Or take a look at its ***[tests](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/3ec2599d13c1c4d6ab7c5bd291b8ff31e625915e/spec/paperclip/validators/attachment_content_type_validator_spec.rb)*** which contain more examples.

Answer (score 1):

validates_content_type accepts `:if => Proc.new{|r| !r.content_type.blank?}` in it's options hash, perhaps that would solve your problem.

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip#

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me;

```
validates_attachment :image1, :presence => true,
                         :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" },
                         :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes }
```