# Why is paperclip upload giving Trying to link error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip

So I have these files

**deal.rb**

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  #there is more code after this
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :deal
  has_attached_file :attachment, styles:  { thumb: "100x100!", medium: "200x200!" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

**deals_controller.rb**

```
module Admins
  class DealsController < BaseController
    before_action :find_deal, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @deals = Deal.includes(:images)
    end

    def new
      @deal  = Deal.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
      @deal = Deal.new(deal_params.merge(created_by: current_user.id))
      if @deal.save
        flash[:success] = t('.success')
        redirect_to admins_deals_url
      else
        flash.now[:warning] = t('.failure')
        render :new
      end
    end

   def update
    if @deal.update(deal_params)
      flash[:success] = t('.success')
      redirect_to admins_deals_url
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = @deal.errors[:base].to_sentence
      render :edit
    end
   end

   def destroy
     if @deal.destroy
       flash[:success] = t('.success')
       redirect_to admins_deals_url
     else
       flash.now[:warning] = t('.failure')
       render :index
     end
   end

  private
   def deal_params
     params.require(:deal).permit(:title, :description, :price, :discounted_price, :quantity, :publish_date, images_attributes: [:id, :attachment, :_destroy])
   end

   def find_deal
     @deal = Deal.find_by(id: params[:id])
     unless @deal
       flash[:warning] = t('deals.not_found')
       redirect_to admins_deals_path
     end
   end
 end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user, :current_cart

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: current_user_id)
  end

  def current_user_id
    cookies.signed[:user_id] || session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_cart
    @current_cart ||= (current_user.addressed_cart || current_user.cart) if current_user
  end
end
```

**EDIT**:
Although I don't think application_controller has anything to do with the error

I am creating a deal with nested image attributes. I am using paperclip to upload the images. But I am getting these errors. I don't have any idea what the errors even mean. Here is an image to show the errors.[image]

Here is the pastebin link
[errors on terminal on creating deal](https://pastebin.com/M9qxN7Rj)

Comment: Please post your errors in something like `https://pastebin.com` also. What do you mean by `some merge error` ?  If you changed code, we need to see the git history.

Comment: Error also tells you something on `application_controller.rb:5` so maybe post code from that area as well. 
 Also see  https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2576

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yeah I saw that . But there is no reply on that one.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1771

Comment: @lacostenycoder Its not really what my error is I think

Comment: `rollback` is usually a validation error and yours is a paperclip error.  See what happens if you comment out the validation.

Comment: @lacostenycoder It gives `Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError`. Its required now according to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897725/papercliperrorsmissingrequiredvalidatorerror-with-rails-4)

Comment: can you post the code that was working vs what broke?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167919/discussion-between-jayanti-hari-and-lacostenycoder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a validation error.  Try this for your validation:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => /image/
```

Or for other variations you can see [Validate Attachment Content Type Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181845/validate-attachment-content-type-paperclip)

UPDATE after testing your code seems this was a validation error because Paperclip creates an image but doesn't know about the `belongs_to` association. You can make it optional because by default rails 5 requires the `belongs_to` id field.

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :deal, optional: true
  has_attached_file :attachment, styles:  { thumb: "100x100!", medium: "200x200!" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```